# Calculate first order differential equation eigenvectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a system of first order defferential equation  that has the coefficient matrix in the picture. I calculated the eigenvalues
Eigenvalues: $+i,  -i$

$$   Q =  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

((   Picture for references [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVQxo.jpg)    ))
but I could not find any **eigenvector** for this. How should I handle this system? Can i find a exponential matrix for this system in order to solve it and how?

Comment: Yes it is the matrix

Comment: How can i do this ? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

$$\pmatrix {x'\\y'\\z'\\w'}=  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \pmatrix {x\\y\\z\\w}$$

Start by solving the smaller system:
$$\pmatrix {x' \\y'}=\pmatrix {0 & -1 \\1 & 0}\pmatrix { x \\y}$$
Or :
$$x'=-y$$
$$y'=x$$
$$\implies  x''+x=0  \text { and } y=-x'$$
Then solve the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
z'&=-w \\
w'&=2x+z\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
z''&=-2x-z \\
w&=-z' \\
\end{cases}
$$